# Creating new variable and Recoding SAS

Tags: sas

I was wondering if there is a way to create new variable and re-coding it based on a range of values. Is it possible to give a range or I have to specify each value.

```
data recode ;
set old ;
if value =
 {(291.0-291.5) OR (295.2) OR (297.3- 297.7) OR (300.5) OR (305.8)} 
then care = 'new' ;
if value =
 {(500.1-501.5) OR (595.2)} 
then care = 'old';
ELSE care = 'other';
run ;
```

Comment: Take a look at `proc format`: http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi27/p056-27.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SAS has the `in` operator, but that won't work for you because it only works with integers or lists.  It explicitly does not work with ranges.

The smallest change that will work is:

```
data recode ;
set old ;
if ((291.0 le value le 291.5)  OR (297.3 le value le 297.7) OR (value in (295.2,300.5,305.8)))
then care = 'new' ;
if 500.1 le value le 501.5 or value=595.2
then care = 'old';
ELSE care = 'other';
run ;
```

That's a lot of typing, though.

`PROC FORMAT` is a great idea, as J_Lard points out.

```
proc format;
  value caref
  291.0-291.5,297.3-297.7,295.2,300.5,305.8 = 'new'
  500.1-501.5, 595.2 = 'old'
  other='other'
  ;
quit;
data _null_;
  input value;
  care=put(value,caref.);
  put value= care=;
  datalines;
200
291
291.3
291.7
297.0
297.5
295.2
300.5
300.7
500.0
500.1
500.5
595.2
595.5
;;;;
run;
```

Those ranges work nicely with it, and you can read them in from a datafile (see `CNTLIN` option on `PROC FORMAT`) or excel or whatever.

You could also set up arrays and check the value against the various array values.

There are other solutions, but format is probably the most appropriate for your particular need particularly without being very complex.